# How do I repeat certain fields as needed in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a slideshow model to which I need to add images and captions `n` times, where `n` is the number of slides on each slideshow. This depends on slides.

The following is the model:

```
class SlideShow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=False, max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(choices=SLIDESHOW_TYPES, default=SLIDESHOW_TYPE_DEFAULT, max_length=20)

    height = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    auto_play = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    loop_play = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    random = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    display_time = models.DecimalField(blank=False, decimal_places=3, max_digits=5)    
    transition_speed = models.DecimalField(blank=False, decimal_places=3, max_digits=5)

    music_file = models.FileField(blank=True,upload_to=gen_slideshowimage_upload_dir_func('music'))
    music_loop = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    slide_count = models.IntegerField()

    # repeat the below fields as per the slide_count
    image = models.FileField(blank=False,upload_to=gen_slideshowimage_upload_dir_func('images'))
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=25)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The last two fields must be repeated per the slide count.

I don't want images on a separate model and linking with Tabular admin or relationships. How do I accomplish this with Django?

Comment: Is there anything else you need to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Master/Slave Table is correct way to handle this. (It called [Many to One Relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)):

```
class SlideShow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=False, max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(choices=SLIDESHOW_TYPES, default=SLIDESHOW_TYPE_DEFAULT, max_length=20)

    height = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    auto_play = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    loop_play = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    random = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    display_time = models.DecimalField(blank=False, decimal_places=3, max_digits=5)    
    transition_speed = models.DecimalField(blank=False, decimal_places=3, max_digits=5)

    music_file = models.FileField(blank=True,upload_to=gen_slideshowimage_upload_dir_func('music'))
    music_loop = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def slide_count(self):
        return len(self.images_set.all())

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Images(modes.Model):
    image = models.FileField(blank=False,upload_to=gen_slideshowimage_upload_dir_func('images'))
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=25)
    slideshow = models.ForeignKey(SlideShow, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```